# Can't create table for Azure SQL Server database in VS 2015

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2015

I created a SQL Server database on Azure and connected to this database (from SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio 2015).

But when I try to create new table, I got endless:

> "Loading... The design surface is loading"

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the loading info is the result of high CPU and high memory.  You could close other useless pages in project and other apps. Try to restart the VS. Then open the Sql server object explorer slowly(wait a while).  Or reconnect to Azure in VS to try again.

Close high CPU and high memory apps in Task Manager:

[image]

Besides, you could also create table in Azure sql in **Server Explorer**.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you could vote it up or mark it as answer to help other community members. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think many people searching for an answer to this issue are having a simple performance problem. Most of them would just wait a few seconds, instead of googling. We are having a different problem where it fails to load despite fast hardware and no previous issues with it loading quickly.